# Selective meshgrid in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensor

Given the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def combine(x, y):
    xx, yy = tf.meshgrid(x, y, indexing='ij')
    combo = tf.stack([tf.reshape(xx, [-1]), tf.reshape(yy, [-1])], axis=1)
    print(combo)
    
x = tf.constant([11, 0, 7, 1])
combine(x, x)
```

I want to clean combo vector in order to obtain the following tf vector `[(11, 0), (11, 7), (11, 1), (0, 7), (0, 1), (7, 1)]`. Is it possible to do this in Tensorflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can introduce a mask, to do get the desired result-

```
def combine(x, y):
    xx, yy = tf.meshgrid(x, y, indexing='ij')

    #create a mask to take the strictly upper triangular matrix
    ones = tf.ones_like(xx)
    mask = tf.cast(tf.linalg.band_part(ones, 0, -1)  - tf.linalg.band_part(ones, 0, 0) , dtype=tf.bool) 
    x = tf.boolean_mask(xx, mask)
    y = tf.boolean_mask(yy, mask)

    combo = tf.stack([x, y], axis=1)
    print(combo)

x = tf.constant([11, 0, 7, 1])
a = combine(x, x)

#output
[[11  0]
 [11  7]
 [11  1]
 [ 0  7]
 [ 0  1]
 [ 7  1]],
```